# docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I got this error after I ran the command below:

`sudo docker run -it --rm --net=host --name=ncsdk --privileged -v /dev:/dev:shared -v /media/data2/NCS/:/media/data2/NCS/ image_name:latest /bin/bash`

When I killed the previous container and wanted to start the container again, I got the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused "open /dev/console: input/output error"".

If I removed the `--privileged -v /dev:/dev:shared` option, it works. I guess the `/dev` must have been locked somewhere but I don't know how to release it.

How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated!

**Update**:

I am using Docker-ce version 17.09. After a system reboot, the error was gone. But it happened again on the second try.